# SSIS Google Analytics - Code 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to extract data from Google Analytics, using KingswaySoft - SSIS Integration Toolkit, in Visual Studio, but I'm getting this error:

> *Code 429: Too Many Requests. (Error Type / Reason: Too Many Requests, Detailed Message:
> "Exhausted property tokens for a project per hour. These quota tokens will return in under an hour. To learn more, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quotas*

I've searched on GA, but I couldn't find what is my actual tokens consumption per hour and what is the solution to solve this.

I have two different data flows in SSIS to extract to data (due to "transactions" metric being incompatible):

[image]

On the 1st connector:

Metrics:

-TotalUsers
-Sessions

Dimensions:

-campaignName
-Country
-dateHour
-deviceCategory
-sourceMedium

On the 2nd connector:

Metrics:

-Transactions

Dimensions:

-campaignName
-Country
-dateHour
-deviceCategory
-sourceMedium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quota is defined on the [Analytics Property Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quotas) page

If its a standard google analytics account you can only send 5000 requests per hour to that property if its a 360 account you can send 50000

> Core Tokens Per Property Per Hour  5,000   50,000

## understanindg quota usage.

Each request your application in this case third party ssis google analytics connector makes to google analtics counts as a single request.

If you have a google analytics 360 account you can max make 50000 requests in an hour.

The max rows i can see on your screen shot is set to 10000 So if the request would return more then 10000 rows it will request the net page of results
Which after a bit of math

50000 * 10000 = 500.000.000 rows in total

So if your request returns more then 500,000,000 rows in an hour your going to blow out the per hour quota.

Seeing as you are using a 360 account which would be a professional website which may have a lot of data and you are using the dimension dateHour from April 2022 - today thats what ten months.   Thats what 7.200 hours

I guess it would be possible for you to be getting that much data back.   Do you really need all of that data

Comment: I know that, but I would like to understand what is my current consumption to understand how the 50000 tokens are being consumed and if there's a way to solve it?

Comment: There not tokens they are requests.

Comment: My advice run it for one month at a time and space it out over the day or something you dont need all this data at once

Comment: I don't know anything about KingswaySoft - SSIS Integration Toolkit, but you can get the number of quota tokens consumed by this request and the amount remaining for each quota group by setting returnPropertyQuota to true in the request , see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quotas#property_tokens_quota

see also: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport#request-body